# CURL error "couldn't connect to host" on http server only

Tags: php, curl, proxy

i call a `CURL` code for calling a URL (the URL sends an email).
When i call the URL from the browser, it works, but when i execute it from the curl php code, it doesn't work.

also, **the exact same curl code works on my https SSL production server,** but not on my http development server.

The error i get on my development http server is "**couldn't connect to host**".

This is the code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$requestedUrl = http://XXX.XXX.XX.XX/myproject/index.php?entryPoint=viewReport&record=.....etc..

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $requestedUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
if ($data === FALSE) {
    $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("error = " . print_r(curL_error($ch),true));
}

curl_close($ch);
```

i read every post there is on this issue. 
i don't know if i'm behind proxy or not and i dont know how to get the ip of the proxy if i'm behind one.

i have tried adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);`

tried adding :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://XXX.XXX.XX.XX"); //your proxy url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "80"); // your proxy port number
```

tried opeining port 1080 in the firewall (which is open for any http address).

i'm out of ideas, so please help me :)

Comment: Can you wget that url (index.php) from cli?

Comment: Thank you Denis, i called wget from the development linux server console. i called "wget http://XX.XX.XX.XX/myproject/index.php" (if that what you meant i should do). and it sais "connecting to XX.XXX.XX.XX:80... failed: connection timed out". what does that mean?

Comment: It means that your servers don't "see" each other, this falls in system admin domain, and i am not sure how to resolve it. 
Your dev server should have an access to the internet, and it seems that it doesnt have it now...

Comment: thanks but the firewall is open for http requests. i can browse the project in the server from my browser (its a CRM system) and there are no two servers only one. i called wget from the server to the server ip itself (same ip) and it didnt connect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just changed the IP of the url to "localhost" and it worked :)
$requestedUrl = http://localhost/myproject/index.php?entryPoint=viewReport&record=.....etc..

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue few days back. What I did is add ip in host file. Let me explain this:

1. your dev server is abc.com and your curl url is xyz.com/...
2. get ip of xyz.com (I used ping xyz.com)
3. add this IP in host file of abc.com server like `127.0.0.1 xyz.com`

In my case abc.com was hosted in dedicated server, So I could make this change. I don't know how to do in shared hosting. May be server guy or hosting provider may help.

Comment: thank you , but i dont understand... the code of the project is in the development server itself, in the curl request, i call the same ip as the development server itself, so how can the curl call a different ip? and if it is the same server (localhost) why do i need to make ping to it?